# azure vm outbound requests limited

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

I have a number of virtual machines(resource manager) setup and running Windows Server 2008. On these machines I have an application running which makes a request to an endpoint. Each machine could make up to 40 requests in a short period of time.

The Url for these requests are unique each time. Only a small amount of these requests are getting through, the requests to this endpoint are logged so I can view incoming request.

It looks like they are being limited/blocked. The same application works with out any problems on Google Compute

Does Azure impose any kind of throttling or limit outbound requests?

Comment: When you say "it looks like they are being limited/blocked", what specifically do you see? Are the requests TCP? Are they failing? What error message do they spit out?

Answer (score 0):

There is an limit on connections, but this is very high (500K). You can check all limits on this page: [Azure Limits](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/azure-subscription-service-limits/#networking-limits)

Comment: thanks, I did come across this but not sure what it would fall under.